# How to fetch images from URL parallely rather the sequentially in php?

Tags: php

```
<?php

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
    echo "<img src='http://lorempixel.com/400/200/?t=".$i."' />";
}

?>
```

Images are fetched from the URL in sequential order can these be fetched in parallel

Comment: are you trying to show all the images at once?

Comment: What is the purpose of that?

Comment: This has nothing to do with php.

Answer (score 1):

```
PHP ---> HTML ---> Browser ---> loads resources from ---> Server
```

- PHP builds the HTML string

  - You are on the PHP level using string contact and echoing.
  - Nothing is fetched by PHP.
- the HTML is rendered in your browser
- any modern browser will try to fetch the images in parallel, if the server supports parallel resource acquisition (this is also protocol dependend, that's why there is HTTP/2 nowadays)

---

You fetch stuff by using file_get_contents or better curl.
If you really want to fetch things in parallel using PHP, then use guzzle.

Comment: Thanks. I just realised that I posted a very stupid question. I was it in wrong direction. Thank you.

Comment: Glad i could help :)